# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'thal'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I went through a tutorial provided by a user here for classification of heart disease. While following the tutorial I came across a problem and can't find a solution. I get an error saying: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'thal'" . 
Here is the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci)

Here's the program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


hd = pd.read_csv("heart.csv", sep=",", header=None)
hd.iloc[:,1].describe()


IVs = hd.iloc[:,2:13]

DV = hd.iloc[:,1]
DV = pd.get_dummies(DV)  # One-Hot Encoding - required by classification algorithms

# In order to feed the data into a Neural Network, I must turn the data into numpy objects
IVs = IVs.values
DV = DV.values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(IVs, DV, test_size=0.25, random_state=173)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)


# Scale the variables using Z-scores

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()  

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) 

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e0f1061996d3> in <module>()
      6 scaler = StandardScaler()  # generate a scaler object
      7 
----> 8 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) # the scaler object learns the mean and std of X_train
      9 
     10 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) # and scales X_test as well using the parameters of X_train

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    515         if y is None:
    516             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 517             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    518         else:
    519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    588         # Reset internal state before fitting
    589         self._reset()
--> 590         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    591 
    592     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    610         """
    611         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'), copy=self.copy,
--> 612                         warn_on_dtype=True, estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    613 
    614         # Even in the case of `with_mean=False`, we update the mean anyway

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'thal'
```

Comment: As I read from this, you can try with LabelEncoder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312695/python-sklearn-value-error-could-not-convert-string-to-float Try it first then tell me the result.

Comment: Is this the code that I have to use for encoding?
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder

str_cols = hd.columns[hd.columns.str.contains('(?:class|thal)')]
clfs = {c:LabelEncoder() for c in str_cols}

for col, clf in clfs.items():
    hd[col] = clfs[col].fit_transform(hd[col])

Comment: I get this error - AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')

Comment: The error is due to `header=None` used when reading the file, as pointed out in the answer below; please confirm this and, if it indeed resolves your *current* error, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On

```
hd = pd.read_csv("heart.csv", sep=",", header=None)
```

You specify `header=None`, which ignores the labels for the columns, thus creating an array that mixes text with numbers. Removing this argument should fix your issue, i.e.

```
hd = pd.read_csv("heart.csv", sep=",")
```

Alternatively you could explicitly specify the row index of the header in the csv file with `header=0`

Answer (score 0):

As the message at the bottom says: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'thal'` it seems a datatype error. The StandardScaler needs numerical (float) data, but it got a string somewhere and returned error.

There are multiple thigs you can do. If you have categorical variables, do One-Hot Encoding on them. Perhaps you can force a column to be of a certain datatype.

PS: After you load your pandas dataframe, you can check what are the datatypes using `hd.dtypes`. Check if there is some non-numerical column within the IVs.

Comment: I finally figured it out. But my test accuracy is not as good as yours. Only around 67%. Any tips on how to improve it?

Comment: It doesn't mean your model is worse. I used a different dataset, the two accuracies cannot be compared. There are lots of hyperparameters that you can tweak to improve performance. You can: 1) change the architecture of the network (e.g. change no. layers and/or their size); 2) change activation functions; 3) change learning rate (try a lower, with higher no. of epochs); 4) if you didn't, try dropout or other regularization techniques... you name it. Most of Machine Learning is trial and error, try different combinations of these hyperparameters and check what works best! Good luck!